# Automatic printing from web app

Tags: printing, web-applications

I am writing a web app that needs to quickly print a name tag and a parent claim check as we check children in.  I am using a Dymo Twin Turbo (a label print that can have 1 label type on the left and a different sized label on the right).  When I check in a child, it needs to print one on each side of the printer without prompting.  I have found jZebra (which I am still trying to figure out) but it doesn't seem to have the capability to choose which tray it will print to.  Is there another applet or such that would be better, or is there something about jZebra that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in what I came up with:  Dymo has a great JavaScript framework that works with its label writers.  This framework can be found in the developers section of the Dymo website (http://developers.dymo.com/).  The examples provided all use a button to print, instead I used an onLoad event to call my function.  It was my first real attempt at JavaScript, so it took me a while to get it working like I wanted, but it works great!

Comment: Hi Andrew, we are searching for such kind of integration. Do you still have it? And are you willing to share it with me?

Comment: http://developers.dymo.com/ is where I got the JavaScript framework and sample JavaScript that I used as a template.  To my knowledge this only works with Dymo label writers.

Comment: Google Chrome has recently change some of the processes.  The Dymo framework no longer works on Chrome.  The easy fix is to switch to FireFox.